# Segfault error in R 3.2.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0

Tags: r

I have just updated my R to 3.2.1. Whenever I try to check the data frame using fix(), I get 
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x7fff00010bb0, cause 'memory not mapped'

error message when I close the popup window. I never had such issues before and wondering whether it is something to do with R or with the OSX Yosemite. Could please help me in fixing this?

Thanks in advance,
Ezhil

Comment: Did you install from source or did you use the binaries from CRAN?

Comment: I have used the binaries from CRAN

Comment: You probably should take this to https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mac

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue when updating to Yosemite and accidentally realized that a workaround was to click "STOP" instead of closing the popup.  Hope this works for you--I never found another solution.